# clang-format: How to prevent indented block comment?

Tags: c, clang-format

How do I prevent clang-format indenting multi-line block comments? For example, if a source file has this comment:

```
/*
* Block-comment
*/
```

Then clang-format always adds a space at the beginning of the continuation lines:

```
/*
 * Block-comment
 */
```

How can I prevent clang-format adding this space, while still permitting clang-format to reflow long comments (I'm using clang-format v16.0.0)?